# why does the addNotificationBlock crash on an empty list?

Tags: swift, realm

I've got this little code that crashes on an empty list, but works fine when the list was actually fetched from an Object subclass `PopContact`
Any idea why this crashes?

```
class Item: Object {

}
class Container: Object {
    let items = List<Item>()

}

func testRealmListNotification(mContainer: Container?) {
    let list = mContainer?.items ??  List<Item>()
    let token = list.addNotificationBlock { (updatedList: List<Item>) -> () in
        log(updatedList)
    }
    //dispose of token later
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notifications are sent after a write transaction for the Realm that an object is contained in is committed, so a newly created object which has not yet been added to a Realm would never have any notifications. Rather than just silently doing nothing, `addNotificationBlock()` throws an exception to alert you that it would not work.

Comment: I get that, but why not mark the function as throwing? currently its     public func addNotificationBlock(block: (RealmSwift.List<T>) -> ()) -> RealmSwift.NotificationToken

Comment: Swift exceptions are used for runtime errors, not precondition violations.